# enable ssl logs in spring boot application from applicaiton.properties

Tags: spring, ssl

I wanted to print the SSL handshake debug log, this can be achieved easily by using jvm argument `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose`.

My scenario, need to enable the ssl debug logs on a third-party springboot application image. Is it possible to use the jvm arguments in `application.properties` to print the SSL debug level log?

I don't have the option to update the Dockerfile to use `java -Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose  applicaiton.jar ....`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do exactly that with application.properties but you should be able to get close by adding this:

```
logging.level.javax.net=TRACE
```

Have a look at [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-custom-log-levels) to see how to set logging levels in application.properties

Comment: Adding this option didn't print any logs on the ssl handshake

Comment: Did it show any TRACE logging? Do you know which packages/classes are involved in the ssl handshake? Logging for these need to be set to TRACE.

Comment: I ended up passing `-Djavax.net.debug=all` as a java option. From the spring documentation link, the `javax.net` package not listed as supported.

Comment: This is useful info. Can you please post the link to supported/not supported packages.

Comment: With reference to the [oracle link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) If i add `logging.level.javax.net.debug=all` it is reporting ALL is not an option. And based on [spring log](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.13.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html) there is no mentioning of javax.net. Also when I use `logging.level.javax.net.ssl = debug` no SSL related info is getting printed.